# Добавление банковской каты в Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, objective-c

Появилась задача по добавлению банковской карты в apple wallet, знаю, что для этого нужно получить разрешение от apple. Скажите, какие данные по карте нужны для добавления в apple wallet? Номер, cvc, имя держателя...?

И я пытаюсь создать объект PKAddPaymentPassViewController:

```
[[PKAddPaymentPassViewController alloc] initWithRequestConfiguration:passDetails delegate:self]
```

Всегда возвращается знание nill, при этом

```
[PKAddPaymentPassViewController canAddPaymentPass]
```

Возвращает YES. Я так понимаю, этот объект будет nill до тех пор, пока Apple не разрешит добавлять карты в Apple Wallet?

Answer (score 0):

В Xcode выделите корневой файл проекта, затем в TARGETS выберите свой ап. Во вкладке Capabilities активируйте Wallet. Должно получиться как на рисунке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]